# Can't view Laravel project in browser with Vagrant

Tags: laravel, vagrant, vagrantfile

I am trying to get a Vagrant/Laravel setup going, but there is only one problem: when I run `php artisan serve` on my Vagrant VM, and try to view the project on my host machine browser, the browser says it can't connect/page isn't found.

Here is my Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "bootstrap.sh"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.name = "dev_host"
  end
end
```

After I `vagrant up`, I cd into my Laravel project folder and run `php artisan serve` and it runs on localhost:8000, so I go to 192.168.50.4:8000 and it does not show up.

Any comments are appreciated!

Comment: did you try going to "localhost:8000" in your broweser?

Comment: Have you tried forwarding port 8000 to host? IE: `config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8000, host: 8000`

Comment: @TheShiftExchange That does not work as it is trying to access port 8000 on the host machine. I tried, and still the page did not show up

Comment: @berrberr I tried the forwarded port and it still will not show up

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to bind the PHP server to the specified IP (192.168.50.4), or to all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Even the port forwarding uses the implicit NAT interface instead of the loopback (localhost, 127.0.0.1) on the VM.

Comment: How do you bind the PHP server to the IP? Is there a setting that I'm missing somewhere? Thanks for the response

Comment: I know nothing of Laravel, but a quick googling suggests `php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works great! I don't know why I was struggling so much

Answer (score 3):

I was facing same problem

I made changes in vagrantfile

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"    
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8000
```

and ran following command to start laravel

```
php artisan serve --port=8000 --host=192.168.33.10
```

It works for me

Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo php artisan serve --port=80 --host=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

In your Vagrantfile, you must allow the redirect port.

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8000
```

Then restart your VM, `vagrant reload` and after,

```
sudo php artisan serve --port=80 --host=0.0.0.0
```

Guest needs to know that through port 80, it will use host 8000.

After these changes, I typed in my browser: `localhost: 8000`

This worked for me.